# rename file with the name of installer name in NSIS installer?

Tags: windows, installation, nsis

I'm working with NSIS installer. I need to change file defined in install path to the same installer name.

I try to use rename function like:

```
Rename "$INSTDIR\app.exe" "$INSTDIR\installname.exe"
```

but I need the installer name automatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [constants](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.2.3), `$EXEFILE` is the filename, or `$EXEPATH` for the full path. If you want the name attribute you used in your source file, it is `$(^Name)`...

Comment: I'm try to use $EXEFILE ins the file name Rename "$INSTDIR\app.exe" "$INSTDIR\$EXEFILE" but nothing change

Comment: I need the name because the installer will download form internet with name for example 1.exe I need to track install with the file name not by source name

Comment: work's fine now with : Rename "$INSTDIR\app.exe" "$INSTDIR\$EXEFILE"

Answer (score 1):

From [FileFunc header](http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?s=&threadid=203228&goto=lastpost) you can combine [`GetExeName`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/GetExeName) and [`GetFileName` macros](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NSIS_Beyond_a_Traditional_Installation) to get the installer's name:

```
!include "FileFunc.nsh"
OutFile test.exe

section main

    ${GetExeName} $R0
    ${GetFileName} "$R0" $R1

    MessageBox MB_OK "My installer's exe is $R1"
sectionend
```

Now you can test it yourself.